# Numpy dotproduct weird behaviour

Tags: python, numpy

I am using python3.5 and i have question: Why np.dot() is behaving like this?

```
>> a = np.array([[1,2,3,4]])
>> b = np.array([123])
>> np.dot(a,b)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: shapes (1,4) and (1,) not aligned: 4 (dim 1) != 1 (dim 0)
>>np.dot(b,a)
array([123, 246, 369, 492])
```

Comment: Not really an answer but an observation from the documentation is that this function was more developed with performance in mind than with flexibility (see the comment on the output parameter: "This is a performance feature. Therefore, if these conditions are not met, an exception is raised, instead of attempting to be flexible."). Therefore, I could imagine that for the same reason, no effort was made to also allow for your input.

Answer (score 2):

From `help(np.dot)`, we learn that, `np.dot(x,y)` is a sum product over **the last axis of `x`** and the **second-to-last of `y`**

In the case of `np.dot(a, b)`, the last axis of `a` is 4 and the length of the only axis of `b` is 1.  They don't match: fail.

In the case of `np.dot(b, a)`, the last axis of `b` is 1 and the 2nd to last of `a` is 1.  They match: success.

#### Workarounds

Depending on what your intention is for `np.dot(a,b)`, you may want:

```
>>> np.dot(a, np.resize(b,a.shape[-1]))
array([1230])
```

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html) for `numpy.dot(x, y)`:

> For 2-D arrays it is equivalent to matrix multiplication, and for 1-D arrays to inner product of vectors... For N dimensions it is a sum product over the last axis of `x` and the second-to-last of `y`:

So, where you have:

```
a = np.array([[1,2,3,4]])  # shape is (1, 4), 2-D array (matrix)
b = np.array([123])        # shape is (1,),   1-D array (vector)
```

- `np.dot(b, a)` works (`(1,) * (1, 4)`, the relevant dimensions agree)
- `np.dot(a, b)` doesn't (`(1, 4) * (1,)`, the relevant dimensions don't agree, the operation is undefined. Note that the 'second-to-last' axis of `(1,)` corresponds to its one and only axis)

This is the same behaviour as if you have two 2-D arrays, i.e. matrices:

```
a = np.array([[1,2,3,4]])  # shape is (1, 4)
b = np.array([[123]])      # shape is (1, 1)
```

- `np.dot(b, a)` works (`(1, 1) * (1, 4)`, inner matrix dimensions agree)
- `np.dot(a, b)` doesn't (`(1, 4) * (1, 1)`, inner matrix dimensions don't agree)

If however you have two 1-D arrays, i.e. vectors, neither operation works:

```
a = np.array([1,2,3,4])   # shape is (4,)
b = np.array([123])       # shape is (1,)
```

- `np.dot(b, a)` doesn't work (`(1,) * (4,)`, but can only define the inner product for vectors of the same length)
- `np.dot(a, b)` doesn't work (`(4,) * (1)`, same)

Comment: Technically `b` is (1,) array, 1d with 1 element, not (1,1).  But for this calculation it's the 2d shape of `a` that matters.

Comment: Indeed, I realised this too. Editing answer now.